# Image cropping script now showing broken link

Tags: php, image-processing

I've been using the following PHP script for years.  Suddenly, a couple weeks ago, it stopped working.  The images it creates, which in turn are embedded into a webpage, show up as broken links.  If I remove the content type lines (to send text), the image text appears to be sending fine.  I have a separate script that fetches images, uses this script to crop them, then saves off the output locally.  I looked at the saved off .png files.  They all have a filesize (30k or so).

I fear my hosting service has updated PHP and broken something (again).  Anyone have any idea what happened?

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
$w=$_GET['w'];
$h=isset($_GET['h'])?$_GET['h']:$w;
$x=isset($_GET['x'])?$_GET['x']:0;
$y=isset($_GET['y'])?$_GET['y']:0;
$filename="http://".$_GET['src'];
//echo $filename;
$result_array = getimagesize($filename);
//exit();

if ($result_array !== false) {
    $mime_type = $result_array['mime'];
    switch($mime_type) {
        case "image/jpeg":
            header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
            break;
        case "image/gif":
            header('Content-type: image/gif');
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename); 
            break;
        case "image/png":
            header('Content-type: image/png');
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename); 
            break;
        case "image/bmp":
            header('Content-type: image/bmp');
            $image = imagecreatefrombmp($filename); 
            break;
        default:
            echo "Unsupported image type";
    }

    $resized = imagecreatetruecolor(1200, 1200);
    imagecopyresampled($resized, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1200, 1200, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
    $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
    imagecopy ( $crop, $resized, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h );
    imagepng($crop);
} else {
    echo "file is not a valid image file";
} 

?>
```

Comment: If you're getting response data when `content-type: text/plain`, then the request is well-formed. However, with the image mime-types, the actual data returned may not be formatted properly for the reply mime-type. Any chance the data files have become corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the old "if you ask a question on stack overflow, you'll figure out the problem a minute later" adage has come true again.

Almost certainly my host updated PHP.  The line `#!/usr/bin/php -q` was getting added to the beginning of the `PNG` file for some reason.  I removed that line and everything is alive again.